# Unable to use classes contained in a class library folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, class

I have a class library and it has a folder. My projects classes are in that folder. I can use the class which is without that folder, but I can't use classes which are in that folder. For example:

**Without that folder:**

```
Example exmp = new Example();
```

I can use exmp normally.

**In the folder:**

```
User user = new User();
```

I'm using asp.net framework 3.5 with c#

> stack trace : at MedulaRADClassLib.MedulaClasses.Kullanici..ctor() at
>   KlinikMuhasebe.Giris.f_GirisYap() in
>   C:\Users\cagin_arslan\Desktop\Medula V3 Gerçek 5 Haziran
>   2009\V3_Gercek\KlinikMuhasebe\Giris.aspx.cs:line 59
>
> inner exception : An error occurred loading a configuration file:
>   Failed to map the path '/'

That problem is only on my computer. The other computers in the team haven't got the same problem.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please update it: Which language? Are you using a library? And why are you suddenly talking about a configuration file? Where does that come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started my project with administrator privileges and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well it sounds like something either in the `User` constructor or something it calls, or in the User's static initializer, or something that calls. Or possibly in the classloader which is looking for that class (if it's Java).

If you post the *full* stack trace of the exception it's likely to give a lot more of a clue -  in particular, which class is throwing the exception!

(You should also say what platform you're on. Is this Java, .NET, something else?)

A [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22An+error+occurred+loading+a+configuration+file%22+%22Failed+to+map+the+path%22&btnG=Search) for

```
"An error occurred loading a configuration file" "Failed to map the path"
```

finds quite a few hits suggesting it's ASP.NET, with [one solution](http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2007/12/01/WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration-throws-Failed-to-map-the-path-_27002F0027002E00_.aspx) suggesting running VS2005 as an administrator...

Comment: i m using asp.net framework 3.5 with vista. 

   Kullanici kul = new Kullanici();

stack trace :    at MedulaRADClassLib.MedulaClasses.Kullanici..ctor()
   at KlinikMuhasebe.Giris.f_GirisYap() in C:\Users\cagin_arslan\Desktop\Medula V3 Gerçek 5 Haziran 2009\V3_Gercek\KlinikMuhasebe\Giris.aspx.cs:line 59

inner exception : An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that stack trace. Then have a look at the type initializer for Kullanici... what does it do in a static constructor or static variable initializers?

Answer (score 0):

be sure that the user account which the program runs on, has file read / write / modify privileges

Comment: DÜn akşam bilgisayarımı kapatmadan evel hiç bi sorun yoktu. Fakat bilgisayarı yeniden açtığımda bu hatayla karşılaştım. İzinlerle lakalı bir sorunolduğunu sanmıyorum. ama yinede kontrol ediyorum.

Comment: Please write comments in English - they'll be more useful to the *vast* majority of users of the site.